# Responsive Circle-cropped photos

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, responsive-design

On my site, I've created these little quote boxes that contain a 2-4 line quote, a byline and byline description (or title/subtitle, whatever), and a circularly cropped photo, absolutely positioned at the bottom left of the box. I've done a basic [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GURFw/1/).

(The way it works in my actual code is that I have a SASS mixin, to which my class feeds the circle diameter.):

**haml**

```
.circle-photo-div{ style: "background: url(#{photo_url})" }
```

**sass**

```
.circle-photo-div
  @include circle-photo(110)
  position: absolute
  bottom: -19%
  left: -7%

@mixin circle-photo($diameter)
  width: #{$diameter}px
  height: #{$diameter}px
  border-radius: #{$diameter / 2.0}px
  -webkit-border-radius: #{$diameter / 2.0}px
  -moz-border-radius: #{$diameter / 2.0}px
  margin: 1em auto
  background-size: cover
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-position: center center
  -webkit-border-radius: 99em
  -moz-border-radius: 99em
  border-radius: 99em
  border: 5px solid white
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
```

At any rate, now I've made the page fully responsive -- with the exception of these circle photos.

The trouble is, if the page expands, I want the photo to expand as well, and I don't know of a way to feed the new ideal diameter to my class to feed it to the sass mixin. So I have a page that scales perfectly, but for these photos that are either too tiny or too large.

Any idea how to do this -- to have a circle-cropped photo that responsively resizes and maintains its relative position at the bottom left of its box (which, I think, means that its absolute positioning must change as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being vw/vh.

> http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

If I made the circle-dimensions percentage-based, the circles would turn into ellipses, unless the height of the container were equal to the width of the container, which is almost never the case (an 80% x 80% circle in a 100px x 200px container is actually 80px by 160px).

The trick was to make the circle diameter a function of the container/window **width** alone, by using the vw unit. That way, the image resized with the window, without distorting into ovals.

Comment: Hi there, could you post an example of your finished working method?